# Does StreamListener internally call MessageChannel.send(Message<?> message)

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In our application, we use kafka and have a spring cloud input stream like so

```
@Component
public interface SomeChannel {
    @Input(ChannelNames.SOME_INPUT)
    MessageChannel someInput();
}
```

Now a coworker is recommending adding a ChannelInterceptor implementation that implements the preSend method. However in our code base no one seems to be calling the `MessageChannel.send(Message<?> message)` on this input channel but we do have a StreamListener like shown below

```
    @StreamListener(ChannelNames.SOME_INPUT)
    public void process(final String strMessage) throws Exception {
```

**My Question**
I am thinking the preSend will never be invoked. Am I missing something here and it might still get invoked (perhaps through the StreamListener code calling `MessageChannel.send(Message<?> message)` internally or in some other way) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the binder sends the incoming message to the channel.